# REST Route not found in /wp-json

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Try to create a custom REST API in wp. This is my code:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_webhook_endpoint');

function register_webhook_endpoint() {
  register_rest_route('my-plugin/v1', '/action', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'handle_webhook_request',
  ));
}

function handle_webhook_request(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  // Process the webhook request
  $data = $request->get_body(); // Get the request body
  // Perform actions based on the received webhook data

  // Return a response if needed
  return new WP_REST_Response('Webhook received.', 200);
}
```

Added in functions.php of my Wordpress theme.

Unfortunately, no new namespace was added. What am I missing?